# jasypt in cmd: cannot find main class

Tags: batch-file, command-line, program-entry-point, jasypt

I am using `jasypt 1.9.2` in Windows 7 x64 `cmd`. Here's `encrypt.bat` content:

```
ECHO ON


set SCRIPT_NAME=encrypt.bat
set EXECUTABLE_CLASS=org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI
set EXEC_CLASSPATH=.
if "%JASYPT_CLASSPATH%" == "" goto computeclasspath
set EXEC_CLASSPATH=%EXEC_CLASSPATH%;%JASYPT_CLASSPATH%

:computeclasspath
IF "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%c in (%~dp0lib\*.jar) DO set EXEC_CLASSPATH=!EXEC_CLASSPATH!;%%c
IF "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set JAVA_EXECUTABLE=java
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto execute
set JAVA_EXECUTABLE="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"


:execute
%JAVA_EXECUTABLE% -classpath %EXEC_CLASSPATH% %EXECUTABLE_CLASS% %SCRIPT_NAME% %*
```

I got this error(I also tried `cd /d [the dir where encrypt.bat is located]` and the error persists):

[image]

The error message points out that the main class of `org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI` is no where to be found. I don't understand this. I tried to change `JAVA_HOME` value in system variables and no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally downloaded again the original release and it works. Seems that I messed something up when I was trying to edit the `encrypt.bat`... I noticed this difference:

With `@echo on`, I see this output in working version:

```
C:\Users\myname>FOR %c in (C:\Users\myname\Documents\[APP]\jasypt-1.9.2-dist_new\bin\..\lib\*.jar) DO set EXEC_CLASSPATH=!EXEC_CLASSPATH!;%c
```

And in my answer I see this:

```
C:\Users\myname>FOR %c in (C:\Users\myname\Documents\[APP]\jasypt-1.9.2-dist_new\bin\lib\*.jar) DO set EXEC_CLASSPATH=!EXEC_CLASSPATH!;%c
```

Note the `..` before `lib`.

Also: **don't put jaspyt in some path with space! It also cause error, even with quotes.**

Comment: Putting jaspyt folder directly in C drive i.e. "C:\jasypt-1.9.2\bin" thus avoiding the spaces did the trick for me.

Comment: I don't have any spaces in my path and still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a same issue when I put unzipped jasypt-1.9.2 folder inside Program Files. You need to move jasypt-1.9.2 folder to C: drive. You should be able to encrypt string without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with version 1.9.3 . I did the following steps to get it to work:

1. I cloned the project form its root (https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt.git)
2. I compiled and packaged the project in `/jasypt/` directory using maven (this is the project that is used by the script)
3. I created the a `lib` next to `bin` directory and then I copied the generated jar files into it
4. then I ran the encrypt.bat again

This way I solved the problem.

Comment: This one fixed it for me on macOS. :)

Answer (score 0):

call the encrypt.bat/decrypt.bat file instead of the .sh file while you are running from the windows machine.